# React patterns without globals/singletons

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, reactjs, global, flux

I've seen a few comments from other people who are also wary of using global dispatchers and stores as advocated by Flux.  I'm wondering, what alternative design patterns have you used?

**Update**

After becoming more familiar with how `react-redux` works, I realized that it doesn't involve a global singleton at all, but rather just puts a store on [React context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), which I think is a fantastic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flummox](https://github.com/acdlite/flummox/) is a nice Flux implementation that doesn't rely on singleton stores/dispatcher.

The issue with singletons is mostly if you want to run React on the server. If you're only running on the client, it's a fair assumption that a store/dispatcher only ever serves one user. So you can assume that the state in a store is state that belongs to that user. But you can't make that assumption on the server, since the same singleton will be used for multiple requests/users. You can still use singletons on the server though, but you have to pass user id to all actions and methods on the stores.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using Redux, which is even more extreme, with only one global store.  But I sometimes wish I could make separate stores for dialogs and things that have temporary state, because having each letter a user types into an input go all the way through the Redux store is a bit slow in my complex RIA, even with pure render optimizations, in debug mode.

Comment: You can still use component local state. You don't have to put everything in your Redux store. Some state is truly local to a component, and it can make things simpler (and faster) to place it in a component.